# How deep must a lake be for fish or squid to spawn in it?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition

I have a small Lake in front of my house in Minecraft. It is currently 1 block deep.

My Question is, how deep (in blocks) must it be that I can fish in it and make squid spawn in it?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

According to the Minecraft Wiki page on [squid](https://minecraft.wiki/w/Squid) and [fishing](https://minecraft.wiki/w/Fishing), squid will spawn at `any depth water, any light level`, and the fishing requirements are:

> at minimum, the body of water should be 1 block by about 10 for casting distance. The water can be 1×1, but this requires the player to cast upwards so that the bobber will land in the water. This ensures the bobber's initial velocity is wasted moving up, so that it does not hit any blocks falling back down.

Comment: As an added note: I have successfully caught fish in a man-made 2x2 pool.

Comment: read in detail my second footnote

Answer (score 0):

Squids are only able to spawn at levels above y=4o. If the house is built in classic flat mode, then it will be hard, but not impossible, to spawn a squid. You would need to get a small body of water above y=40.

If it is in a normal world on ground surface, then there should probably be no problem as long as the lake is large enough to fit fish/squids. One block in theory should be deep enough as long as it is wide and long enough to spawn squids.

I am sadly unsure currently what is the levels that fish can spawn at though.

Good luck and I hope this answer helped!☺

Answer (score 0):

I have found that if you dig a hole of 3 blocks down, 4 blocks wide, and 5 blocks long, it will spawn fish. This will not, however, spawn squid.